# Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead

Tags: react-native, warnings

This warning appears each time I open the Drawer menu or when any kind of default animations occur in my react native application. [image]Is this an issue with the new version 0.62?

Anyone please help how to get rid of this warning.

***Specifications:***

react-native-cli: **2.0.1**

react-native: **0.62.0**

Comment: If it's inside a library you are using for animation, you should update this library to a newer version. If it's your code, you should stop using this method. Can you manage to isolate where exactly the problem occurs?

Comment: @Konstantin I am not using this method anywhere in my code. Also I am not using any kind of animations. I have a drawer in my app which is when opened throws this warning. It is the built-in animation when the drawer gets opened

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Are you using react navigation? This could be it.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7933

Answer (score 3):

> Go to node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/index.js
>
> at line 192 change

```
this.view.getNode().measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight)
```

> to

```
this.view.measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to the latest version of react-navigation - at the time of writing that's `4.3.9`. - [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation).

I had the error popping up on almost every screen - because id last updated the version 9months back - this issue has since been attended to in the latest versions.